# Spring Boot - @RestController annotation gets picked up, but when replaced with @Controller annotation, it stops working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, spring-restcontroller

Here is a dummy project for the same :-

[image: layout]

`BlogApplication.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class BlogApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BlogApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
    }
    
}
```

`HtmlController.java`

```
@Controller  //does not work
OR
@RestController //works
public class HtmlController {

    @GetMapping("/getHtmlFile")
    public String getHtmlFile() {
        return "Bit Torrent Brief";
    }
}
```

Why is it that `@RestController` is able to map `getHtmlFile` but `@Controller` returns 404 when `/getHtmlFile` is hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RestController is the combination of @Controller and @ResponseBody.
when you use @Controller, you should write @ResponseBody before your method return type

Comment: Oh, so the controller was getting initialized!

 I wanted to return a file here and not the response body which is why I wanted to use @Controller. 

Had to add that thymeleaf dependency to render the html, and because of this I did not have to add the ResponseBody annotation

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
public class HtmlController {

    @GetMapping("/getHtmlFile")
    public @ResponseBody String getHtmlFile() {
        return "Bit Torrent Brief";
    }
}
```

This works.